# grails 2.4.2 searchable plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, searchable

I have installed the searchable plugin in grails 2.4.2.

```
compile ":searchable:0.6.9"
```

It is getting installed successfully but when I run the application, it gives this error. I do not have any controllers made. just one domain class which is declared searchable. How to resolve this?

```
Sep 2, 2014 7:34:11 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Sep 2, 2014 7:34:11 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
| Running Grails application
Sep 2, 2014 7:34:24 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Error |
2014-09-02 19:34:57,557 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application:
Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.searchable.SearchableController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initialization of be
an failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass':
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grails.plugin.searchable.SearchableController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exc
eption is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initializat
ion of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'c
ompass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   885 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   907 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableService': Initialization of bean failed; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw excepti
on on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   885 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   907 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested
exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   885 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   907 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 303 | addAll   in java.util.AbstractCollection
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   121 | configure in grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigura
tor
|    39 | configure in grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator
|    93 | buildCompass in grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean
|    58 | getObject in     ''
|    41 | getObject in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   885 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   907 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: I believe that it is because Grails 2.4.x uses Hibernate 4, and the searchable plugin only supports Hibernate 3. Look in you BuildConfig.groovy file. You should be able to use Hibernate 3 with Grails 2.4.x

Comment: And you should go read this blog entry: http://jolorenz.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/how-to-use-searchable-plugin-with-grails-2-3-0-and-hibernate-4-x/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the command line installing the searchable plugin.

grails install-plugin searchable (I am assuming you are using java 1.5+)

once the plugin is installed then try to have make your domain searchable since I believe the Searchable controllers and service classes are created during the installation.

Comment: its not working @user1313900. it says installPlugin wont work in Grails versions above 2.3

Comment: grails install-plugin searchable 0.6.9

Answer (score 0):

What version of Hibernate plugin are you using? Note that Searchable plugin does not work with Hibernate 4; you must use Hibernate 3 instead.